# iOS 4:Compile PJSIP in TCP mode

Tags: iphone, ios, tcp, ios4, pjsip

How to compile PJSIP library in TCP mode for iPhone?

I have the steps but don't know which all files I need to modify.

To enable multitasking support of iOS, set PJ_IPHONE_OS_HAS_MULTITASKING_SUPPORT to 1. Then application can use the API pj_activesock_set_iphone_os_bg() to set iOS background mode setting. Setting the value to 1 will enable TCP active socket to receive incoming data when application is in the background. The default value of this setting is PJ_ACTIVESOCK_TCP_IPHONE_OS_BG. By default, both these settings are enabled on iOS 4 when you run configure-iphone

Can anyone please tell in which all files changes are required to be made in order to compile PJSIP lib in TCP mode.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: pjsip 1.x or pjsip 2.x? You want to use pjsua to build a app or you want to go lower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pjsip 1.x or pjsip 2.x? You want to use pjsua to build a app or you want to go lower?

If you want to use TCP your SIP server/proxy should support that too (there are some SIP Servers that are not properly supporting TCP).

To get the TCP support you don't have to do anything special (1.x) at compilation time, but you have to build your registration uri like this:

`"sip:username@server;transport=TCP"`

Comment: Its pjsip 1.x  and yes our server supports TCP connection. But is this the only change that needs to be done ? Don't need to make those settings and then compile PJSIP ?

Comment: for me that was sufficient, but i am using only pjsua calls (pjsua is part of the pjsip). You have the steps here: http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

Comment: there is one more thing you have to pay attention, the sip server should reply to the pjsip client (running on iOS) on the same port he received the register message. If this is not happening you will get disconnected when on background mode. Will also help if your server can send TCP keep alive packages to the client. As i remember this are the most important things you have to consider.

Comment: i tried and it worked fine. but still i am not able to get calls in background mode after 6 mins.

Comment: if you could get a call in background that means you are using the TCP. But there can be other problems like: what value have u use for reg_timeout? Is your server in the internal network or outside? do u use a session border controller?

Comment: @alinoz does pjsip 2.x supports TCP? if so, is it same like 1.x?

Comment: i only used 1.x but I believe the TCP support was not removed.